# What can the Run app do that the start button can't Windows 7 - 10

Tags: windows-7

My teacher in A+ had us add the Run command to our start menu on Windows 7,so now there's a button you can press and it brings up the Run prompt. But when you press the Windows key, it brings up the start menu and by default, you can type in a file, and it acts as if it were running it as well.

Like I click Start button, click run. It opens the Run prompt, then I can type cmd.exe and it opens command prompt. BUT I can press Start (on keyboard), and immediately type cmd and press enter, and it does the same thing with less steps.

Aside from him saying that "because I told you to" is there any other reason you would put a run button on your start menu?

I think I head something that you can do more with .dll files with the Run prompt, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 1):

It's **good practice**. But ultimately, do what you want.

Not only that but some <strike>stuff</strike> tasks you'll be completing simply won't work by typing it into Start, and you'll realize that and then use Run after all.

Also, if you're worried about extra steps just press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to directly open Run.

I'd also like to point out if you need to move to another Window whilst typing into Start, your entry is **gone**. But in Run, you can navigate back to the Window.

Example:

```
control intl.cpl
```

Or any of [these](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/192806). (Makes it easier to open some control panel dialog windows)

Those definitely won't **work** by pasting them into Start.

**Side note**: To show I'm not bias, I'll point out that rundll32.exe commands do actually **work in Start** (tested on Windows 10). For example: `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,,1` (opens screensaver settings).

Comment: Alright, thanks :) I can see where it would come in handy, but as I don't know much about the deeper interior of a computer, and their OS's is the reason I asked. Now that I know there are some benefits to using it over the plain Start button, I can have a greater appreciation for the button.

Comment: @JohnOlivas If you wanted to know technical limitations you'd probably need to read a book like Windows Internals.